# Windows Authentication in local system

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

This is the default.aspx file

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"Inherits="Default"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
Welcome to sample website:)
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the web.config file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
 <system.web>
 <authentication mode="Windows"/>
 <identity impersonate="true"/>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
 </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
 </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

I am unable to get the windows authentication , I did the required changes in the applicationhost.config file as well.Kindly help me how to proceed ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Your web.config configuration is incomplete.

See: [Enabling Windows Authentication within an Intranet ASP.NET Web application](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application)

There's also plenty other guides/blog posts on setting up Windows Authentication for asp.net if you just search the internet.

You haven't told ASP.NET to deny anonymous users, which is why you don't get the login prompt.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> Note that the  directive within the 
>   section above is what tells ASP.NET to deny access to the application
>   to all “anonymous” users to the site (the “?” character means
>   anonymous user).  This forces Windows to authenticate the user, and
>   ensures that the username is always available from code on the server.